# How to size the view of a Sharing extension view controller that is not a subclass of SLComposeServiceViewController?

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm trying to make a sharing app extension to handle URLs from Safari. The XCode project template provides a ViewController that is a subclass of `SLComposeServiceViewController`. My problem is that my extension is not going to fit into the "standard" sharing template - I need to provide a custom UI for it. So I changed the parent class to the normal UIViewController. My extension continues to load fine in Safari - **but** I can't figure out how to size the UI similar to the `SLComposeServiceViewController`.

My ViewController is initing with full width x height of the device and even after I call `[self setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 320.0f)];` which is recommended if AutoLayout is not used, as a test to see if the size is reduced, nothing happens.

I've tried this in both the simulator and on my iPad with iOS 8 beta 5.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I found a solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28223772/2158465

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the size of my share dialog by doing...

```
let frame = self.view.frame
let newSize:CGSize = CGSize(width:frame.size.width, height:frame.size.height * 2)
self.preferredContentSize = newSize
```

It animated and everything.

Comment: What method did you put this in? I've tried `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad`, to no avail