# iOS 8 Action Extension Display as Banner

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

You may have seen Instapaper's iOS 8 extension where, upon saving to Instapaper in Safari, the entire browser is still visible and a banner animates from the top and automatically hides itself.

I am trying to do something similar with my action extension, but the extension consistently hides the screen.

In the Info.plist I have added the key `NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation` and set it to `NO`.
In the storyboard I have made the background colour of the view clear.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image: Current Extension]

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I redesigned it to just go with the full screen nature of Action Extensions.

Comment: try this link,maybe you'll find something for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979248/ios-8-share-extension-custom-view-controller-size